# R Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) while using tell of the sensitivity package

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am conducting a sensitivity study using the Sensitivity package. When trying to calculate the sensitivity indices with the output data of the external model I get the error specified in the titel.

The output is a three column table stored in a csv file which I read in as follows:

```
day1 <- read.csv("day_1_outputs.csv",header=FALSE)
```

Now when I try to calculate sensitivity indices with the ouput of the first column:

```
tell(sob.pars,day1[,1])
```

I get:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
   invalid 'row.names' length
```

At first I thought I should use a matrix like object because in another study I conducted I generated the ouput from a raster image read in as a matrix which worked fine, but that didn't help.
The help page for tell states using a vector for the model results but even if I store the column of the dataframe before using tell the problem persists.

I guess my main problem is that I don't understand the error message in conjunction with the tell function, sob.pars is a list returned by sensitivity analyses objects constructors from the same package so I don't know to which rownames of that object the message is refering.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: what is `sob.pars`? `day[,1]` won't have rownames. does it work if you use `day[,1, drop = FALSE]`?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out what the problem was. The error is kind of missleading.
The problem was not the row names since these were identical, that's what irritated me in the first place. There was obviously nothing wrong with them.

The actual problem was the column names in sob.pars. These were missing. Once I added these everything worked fine. Thanks rawr anyways (I just only now noticed someone had commented on the question, I thought I would be notified when this happens, but I guess not).